# CD into path from shell script

Tags: shell, batch-file

I have written a program found here [Project](https://github.com/RyanBluth/Mangy-Bat/tree/master/Mangy/src). Its purpose is to make command line navigation quicker by allowing the user to create variables and run custom commands. One thing it allows you to do is `cd` into the path of a stored variable. I achieve this by running the program using the following bat script:

```
@ECHO OFF
set curDir = %cd%
pushd %~dp0
set VAR = ""
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('main.exe %curDir % %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9') do set VAR=%%I & ECHO %%I
type log.txt
popd
%VAR% 2>nul
```

If the program returns the 'cd' command and it is run from the bat script which alters the users current directory outside the context of the program and the bat script.

I want to port this to Linux but cant seem to figure out how to write a shell script that produces the same behavior. Is this possible?

Comment: Please include the bash script that you've worked out so far. Requests to write code without any effort shown on your part are likely to be closed.

Comment: I haven't begun porting yet. I ran a simple test by creating a bash script with 'cd someDirectory' in it. Running this with out the ". " did not alter the users environment while running it with the ". " did, hence why I marked AIG's answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just call the script as `. myScript` (note the space). This allows the script to mess with the running users environment. I have a similar script that I used for moving around our svn repos.